# How to include multiple JS and CSS files in app.html.eex Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, vue-cli-3

I am using `VueCLI3` within Phoenix, and switched to `SplitChunk` feature of webpack4. Through which In past I was creating only 1 `app.js` and `app.css` file, but after enabling `splitChunk` feature now there are almost 5 CSS files and 10 js files.

All are placed in `/priv/static/js` and `/priv/static/css`.

[image]

I have been using this to include single CSS and JS file such as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Routes.static_path(@conn, "/js/app.js") %>"></script>
```

How I can loop through all JS files and include them at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top of my head, you could do something like:

```
<%= for file <- Path.wildcard("../priv/static/js/*.js") do %>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Routes.static_path(@conn, file) %>"></script>
<% end %>
```

But I do have a gut feeling there might be a bigger problem here than this. It feels hacky.